# Why I can not extract data from this dictionary though a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, subset

I'm extracting from `data` which is of type dictionary.

```
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
f = http.request('GET', url)
data = json.loads(f.data.decode('utf-8'))

data[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]

geo = []
n = len(data)
for i in range(n):
    geo.append(data[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"])
```

It returns an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-52e67ffdcaa6> in <module>
     12 n = len(data)
     13 for i in range(n):
---> 14     geo.append(data[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"])

KeyError: 'geometry'
```

This is weird, because, when I only run `data[0]["geometry"]["coordinates"]`, it returns `[7.000275, 43.58554]` without error.

Could you please elaborate on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is occuring because in few of the response dictionaries you don't habe "geometry" key.
Check before appending to geo list, that "geometry" key exists in response dict.

Try following code.

```
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/fr-esr-principaux-etablissements-enseignement-superieur.json'
f = http.request('GET', url)
data = json.loads(f.data.decode('utf-8'))


geo = []
n = len(data)
for i in range(n):
    if "geometry" in data[i]:
        geo.append(data[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"])
print(geo)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that there are places in your data which do not have a "geography" key. As a preliminary matter, your data structure is not technically a dictionary.  It is a 'list' of 'dictionaries'.  You can tell that by using the print(type(data)) and print(type(data[0]) commands.

I took your code but added the following lines:

```
dataStructure = data[0]
print(type(dataStructure))

geo = []
n = len(data)
for i in range(321):
    try:
        geo.append(data[i]["geometry"]["coordinates"])
    except:
        print(i)
```

If you run this, you will see that at index positions 64 and 130, there is no geometry key.  You may want to explore those entries specifically and see whether they should be removed from your data or whether you just need to alter the keyword to something else for those lines.